# provide Enum at DB creation time

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a generic `Food` sqlalchemy model that I want to reuse for different apps.
In each app, I have a `FoodType` enum which contains the different types of food I'll use.

I want to be able to pass this app-specific Enum to my generic model. Any idea on how to do that?

Here is my food model:

```
class Food(Base):
    type = Column(Enum(FoodType, name="l=food_type"))
```

I tried to define an empty enum in my generic model so that it could be overwritten in each app but that apparently doesn't work, it crashes on:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.LookupError) "PIZZA" is not among the defined enum values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Food` a [mixin](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html) instead of a concrete model, and use [`declared_attr`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr) to define `type`:

```
class FoodMixin:
    @declared_attr
    def type(cls):
        return Column(Enum(cls.food_type, name="food_type"))
```

Then in your application create the concrete model as:

```
class Food(FoodMixin, Base):
    food_type = FoodType
```

Another way would be to define a model factory for `Food` that takes the enum type as an argument and produces a model:

```
def food_maker(FoodType, Base):
    class Food(Base):
        type = Column(Enum(FoodType, name="food_type"))

    return Food
```

and in the app:

```
Food = food_maker(FoodType, Base)
```

...Or make the factory return a mixin and inherit from that.