# Provide an enum to model at init time for attribute conversion

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a generic `Food` sqlalchemy model that I want to re-use in several different apps:

```
class Food(Base):
    _type = Column(Integer, index=True, unique=False, nullable=False)
```

The `_type` attribute here is an integer. It could technically be an Enum, but I when I write my generic model, I don't have access to the enum values (they are defined later in the apps). I tried the Mixin approach (see my previous question: [provide Enum at DB creation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560874/provide-enum-at-db-creation-time/58562639#58562639)), but my real use case is slightly more complex than the `Food` example. There are multiple relationships defined on this model, including one that points back to the `Food` model. This forces me, among other issues, to declare several relationships at the app level and I really don't want to do that.

Instead, I would like to do something like this:

```
class FoodType(Enum):
    pass

class Food(Base):
    _type = Column(Integer, index=True, unique=False, nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def type(self) -> FoodType:
        return FoodType(self._type)

    @type.setter
    def type(self, food_type):
        self._type = food_type.value
```

and I wanted to somehow "fill" the `FoodType` enum later at the app level, but it doesn't seem to be possible. I tried to override/extend/subclass `FoodType` but my attempts were unsuccessful.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the only way I found is to "monkey patch" the model/class by giving a subclassed (and extended) enum to the model/class:

```
class FoodType(Enum):
    pass

class Food(Base):

    food_types: FoodType

    _type = Column(Integer, index=True, unique=False, nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def type(self) -> FoodType:
        return self.food_types(self._type)

    @type.expression
    def type(cls):
        return cls._type

    @type.setter
    def type(self, food_type):
        self._type = food_type.value
```

and then in my apps, I can subclass FoodType, add the enum values, and before the call to `create_all` I just need to do:

`Food.food_types = MySubClassedEnum`